# Perform Segue from App Delegate swift

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I need to launch a view controller from the app delegate.

In the way you would perform a segue between view controllers.

I have an if statement that if true needs to show a view controller, this is in the app delegate.

How do I do this from the app delegate?

Comment: Huh? What do you mean "segue to a view controller from the app delegate"? (P.S. I didn't vote to close... Just trying to understand what you mean.)

Comment: Edited, sorry for not being clear.

Comment: Gotcha. Are you using nibs or storyboards?

Comment: I'm using storyboards.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

c_rath's answer is mostly right, but you don't need to make the view controller a root view controller. You can in fact trigger a segue between the top view on the navigation stack and any other view controller, even from the App Delegate. For example, to push a storyboard view controller, you could do this:

**Swift 3.0 and Later**

```
// Access the storyboard and fetch an instance of the view controller
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil);
let viewController: MainViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as! MainViewController;

// Then push that view controller onto the navigation stack
let rootViewController = self.window!.rootViewController as! UINavigationController;
rootViewController.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true);
```

**Swift 2.0 and Earlier**

```
// Access the storyboard and fetch an instance of the view controller
var storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
var viewController: MainViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController") as MainViewController

// Then push that view controller onto the navigation stack
var rootViewController = self.window!.rootViewController as UINavigationController
rootViewController.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
```

Comment: I'm trying to implement this, but it's crashing on the third line of code "var rootViewController..." No errors in the console though. Just "Thread 5: EXC_BREAKPOINT" Any thoughts?

Comment: @jackreichert And you're definitely using a `UINavigationController`?

Comment: @LyndseyScott how will this work if am not using NavigationViewController?

Answer (score 11):

if you want to use `segue` `identifier`, you can use in `Swift` `2.2`.

```
self.window?.rootViewController!.performSegueWithIdentifier("YOUR SEGUE IDENTIFIER", sender: nil)
```

and for Swift 3.1 :

```
self.window?.rootViewController!.performSegue(withIdentifier: "YOUR SEGUE IDENTIFIER", sender: nil)
```

Answer (score 3):

**If you want  segue in  App Delegate  Swift 3.0**

```
  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: PARAM.STATUS) {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.window?.rootViewController?.performSegue(withIdentifier: PARAM.SEGUETOHOME, sender: nil)
            }

        }
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        return true
    }
```

> Note if you not use `DispatchQueue.main.async` than your segue is not
>   perform

Answer (score 2):

You can't actually perform a segue from the AppDelegate since a segue is a transition from one scene to another. One thing you can do however is instantiate a new view controller and present it from the AppDelegate. Something similar to the following should work...

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    var storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    var viewController: MasterViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("viewController") as MasterViewController

    window?.rootViewController = viewController
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true
}
```

Comment: Mostly right, but not entirely true... I tried to explain why in my answer.

Comment: Wrong, you can with performSegueWithIdentifier on the target controller which you retrieve from the window.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what you'd do if your `rootViewController` did **NOT** inherit from `UINavigationViewController`:

Basically you check what the currently presented tab is and then push from **THAT** view controller, rather than the `rootViewController` that inherits from `UITabBarController`.

```
        let root = self.window?.rootViewController as UITabBarController

        switch(root.selectedIndex){
        case 0:
            root.viewControllers?[0].pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
            break;
        case 1:
            root.viewControllers?[1].pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
            break
        default:
            println("Error presenting ViewController")
            break;
        }
```

My application has an initial/rootViewController that inherits from `UITabBarController`, each of it's `UITabBar` Relationship Controllers inherit from `UINavigationController`, allowing me to `pushViewController` from them.

Comment: this helped me using UITabBarController as root.
You might need to update this code (doesn't work for Swift 5)
guard let root = self.window?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController etc.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to instantiate new ViewController, just perform segue from `presentedViewController` like this (swift 3.0+)

```
guard let mainController = self.window?.rootViewController?.presentedViewController as? MainViewController else { return }
mainController.performSegue(withIdentifier: "SEGUE_ID", sender: nil)
```

In case when your application is based on `UITabBarController`, you must:

- fetch UITabBarController
- select proper controller from `viewControllers` collection from `UITabBarController`
- change index of `UITabBarController`
- lastly you can perform segue

Of course you must know the index of your view controller in your `UITabBarController`

Example code:

```
guard let tabBarController = self.window?.rootViewController?.presentedViewController as? UITabBarController else { return }
guard let tabBarViewControllers = tabBarController.viewControllers else { return }
guard let mainViewController = tabBarViewControllers[0] as? MainViewController else { return }
tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0
mainViewController(withIdentifier: "SEGUE_ID", sender: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to perform segue from AppDelegate. Implement segue between ViewControllers in your storyboard. Give identifier to your segue.

```
self.window?.rootViewController!.performSegue(withIdentifier: "your_identifier", sender: nil)
```