# Show view controller after spotlight search

Tags: ios, swift, corespotlight

I'll try to make myself as clear as possible, but english is not my mother tongue so I'm sorry for any inconvenience.

I've been following this http://www.appcoda.com/core-spotlight-framework/ to show some of my app features on the spotlight search, but I'm stuck at the part of showing the view controllers of each feature. Mainly (I think) because my app is a tabbed one. Here's a screenshot of my storyboard:

[image: storyboard]

So when trying to use this method:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, continueUserActivity userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: ([AnyObject]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
    let viewController = (window?.rootViewController as! UINavigationController).viewControllers[0] as! consultaCorralones
    viewController.restoreUserActivityState(userActivity)

    return true
}
```

(consultaCorralones is the view controller I wish to show)

When I run it I get the error:

> Could not cast value of type 'UITabBarController' (0x11041d5d8) to 'UINavigationController' (0x11041d588).

My limited Swift knowledge tells me to change `UINavigationController` to `UITabBarController`, but in doing so I get:

> Could not cast value of type 'UINavigationController' (0x1117b8588) to 'Parcial2.consultaCorralones' (0x10fb83200).

I also tried following [Perform Segue from App Delegate swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27135997/perform-segue-from-app-delegate-swift) but that didn't work.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Try `let viewController = (window?.rootViewController as! UITabBarController).selectedViewController as! consultaCorralones`

Comment: Thanks, but it keeps showing the same error `Could not cast value of type 'UINavigationController' (0x1022f6588) to 'Parcial2.consultaCorralones' (0x1006c1200).`

Comment: I'm trying to guess your view hierarchy; try `let viewController = ((window?.rootViewController as! UITabBarController).selectedViewController as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! consultaCorralones`

Answer (score 0):

`UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController` returns a `UITabBarController`. You need to get `selectedViewController` from it. That will be a `UINavigationController` instance.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, continueUserActivity userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: ([AnyObject]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
    let controller = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController as! UITabBarController
    let navController = controller.selectedViewController as? UINavigationController
    let viewController = navController?.viewControllers[0] as! consultaCorralones
    viewController.restoreUserActivityState(userActivity)
    return true
}
```

Hope it helped.