# performSegue error when come from appDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, crash, segue, uistoryboardsegue

My case is something special, since this works me correctly if the application is opened in normal mode.

This is when I try to do so after receiving a push notification.

inside didReceive notification:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceive notification: UILocalNotification) {
```

i'm calling a function from my `initial view controller(HOME)`

> **That is just the view that is displayed when the application opens when you click on the notification**

```
let homeVC : HomeViewController! = HomeViewController()
homeVC.goAdvertisement(id, data: dataInfo)
```

Within `goAdvertisement` you can find:

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "mySegue", sender: itemData)
```

And that is where the error occurs.

> `libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException`

[image]

At first I thought that it could be that it was giving time to load the view so that I could execute the `performSegue`, and try to give it a delay using:

```
func delay(delay:Double, closure:@escaping ()->()) {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + delay) {
            closure()
        }
    }

self.delay(delay: 4, closure: {
    let homeVC : HomeViewController! = HomeViewController()
    homeVC.goAdvertisement(id, hardwareAd: dataInfo)
}
```

***But it does not work***

Another idea that I had, was to leave aside the `performSegue` and try to use the `present`.

```
let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "myVcId") as! MyController
vc.data = itemData
self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

**But this did not work either** (The crash points to `instantiateViewController` line)

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks.

**UPDATE**

Following [APK APPS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6389464/apk-apps) answer. Finally found a way.

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let homeVC: HomeViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "homeView") as! HomeViewController

let rootViewController = self.window!.rootViewController as! UINavigationController;
rootViewController.pushViewController(homeVC, animated: false);
```

Comment: You can't just create an instance of a view controller and ask it to perform segues; you need to get the instance that is already on screen and ask that to perform the segue.

Comment: Get the instance was not enough, it still failed. I update my question with the final solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> From the `AppDelegate` class you can not perform `segue`. So this line will never work from your `AppDelegate` class.

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "mySegue", sender: itemData)
```

You Need to simple

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let scheduleController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "yourIdentiFier")
self.window!.rootViewController = scheduleController
self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

You can provide Identifier to you controller from your `Main.storyboard` Follow these steps.

- Open Main StoryBoard
- Click Your View Which you want to open
- Select Yellow/ Left button from top of that controller
- Now Open your Utility box which would be in the Right side
- Now Click on the `Show the Identical Inspector`
- Now here you can give your Identity as StoryBoard Id

Comment: Thanks, your idea combine with this other , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27135997/perform-segue-from-app-delegate-swift#27136455, solve my problem