# Swift 3 from appDelegate performSegue is not working after google signin

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am trying to implement **Google login** and its working with signin process but in my app delegate file I have `didSignInFor`  function and inside closure after successful login I am sending the user from `loginVC` to `feedVc`.

And its going to that line and printing what is in the next line but not performing Segue.
Here is the code:

```
func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
    print("Successfully logged into google", user)

    guard let idToken = user.authentication.idToken else {return}
    guard let accessToken = user.authentication.accessToken else {return}

    let credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: idToken, accessToken: accessToken)

    Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (user, error) in
        if error != nil{
            print("ANKIT : Unable to authenticate with firebase")
        } else{
            guard let uid = user?.uid else { return }

            KeychainWrapper.standard.set(uid, forKey: KEY_UID)

            self.window?.rootViewController?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToFeed", sender: nil)

            print("ANKIT : Successfully authenticated with firebase for google")
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me with this error?
cant figure it out why segue is not working..or if anyone had this problem and they figured it out pls share the solution. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Use `main thread` for perform segue

Comment: is window and rootViewController both set to values?

Comment: dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                                print(results)
                                completion(success: true, object: results)
 }) otherwise use like this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> From the AppDelegate class you can not `perform segue`. So this line will never work from your `AppDelegate` class.

```
self.window?.rootViewController?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToFeed", sender: nil)
```

You Need to simple

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let scheduleController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "yourIdentiFier")
self.window!.rootViewController = scheduleController
self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

You can provide Identifier to you controller from your Main.storyboard Follow these steps.

**Open Main StoryBoard**

1. Click Your View Which you want to open
2. Select Yellow/ Left button from top of that controller
3. Now Open your Utility box which would be in the Right side
4. Now Click on the Show the Identical Inspector
5. Now here you can give your Identity as StoryBoard Id

[Check this answer for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27135997/perform-segue-from-app-delegate-swift#27136455)

Answer (score 0):

use main queue while working with UI operations. You get callback by `Auth` in background thread. So in your else condition, use the below code to perform segue

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.window?.rootViewController?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToFeed", sender: nil)

}
```