# Load Tab Bar Controller from AppDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, appdelegate

I have been trying to figure this out by myself, but couldn't.

I want to load a Tab Bar controller from my AppDelegate (After a successful Google Sign in to the application).

I read here how to load a ViewController from AppDelegate

[Perform Segue from App Delegate swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27135997/perform-segue-from-app-delegate-swift)

Code in the example:

```
// Access the storyboard and fetch an instance of the view controller
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil);
let viewController: MainViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as! MainViewController;

// Then push that view controller onto the navigation stack
let rootViewController = self.window!.rootViewController as! UINavigationController;
rootViewController.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true);
```

In this example, my TabBar needs both a name and identifier, from what I understood.

Can someone please explain this to me ? I can't find "identifier" on the Tab Bar Controller , only "Title".

Also, I don't have a navigation controller view in my app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

set storyboard ID here

[image]
and embed the firstViewController in IB in navigationController

```
 let rootViewController = self.window!.rootViewController as! UINavigationController;
 rootViewController.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true);
```

Comment: Thank for the quick reply. So this is Storyboard ID is the identifier. What about the name ? 

About changing root - how is this different from in the example ?

Comment: I just saw you edited the post. I have set the StoryboardID now. It's "MainTabBar". What does embed the firstViewController in IB? in navigationController ? I don't have a navigationController, and what's IB ?

Comment: IB is Interface Builder ,  select the the view controller with the arrow pointing to it's middle from left and , in Editor menu select Embed in navigation controller

Comment: When you say "firstViewController", you mean the view controller where the signing in happens ?

Comment: Sh_Khan, I don't think I understand what you said. I did everything except embeding the LogInController in IB in navigationController. I'm not sure I understand what that means. I need to add a NavigationController to point to my SignInViewController ?

Comment: Or do I need my SignInViewController to inherit from NavigationController ?

Comment: not inherit , NavigationController to point to my SignInViewController is what i mean

Comment: Alright. I embedded in the NavigationController. Anything else that must be done ?

Comment: This seems to be working ! Just one question - There is a "Back" button that allowes the user to go back to Login screen without logging out now. How can I disable it from going back to Login screen like that ?

Comment: select navigation  controller in IB and on the right as Storyboard ID , un check show Navigation bar , also take care all your coming presents will be with push and dismiss will be pop

Answer (score 3):

### iOS 13 Update

From version. iOS 13, 
The *RootViewController* will be initiated in `scene` function located at
 `SceneDelegate.swift` instead of `AppDelegate.swift` file. which looks like this.

[image]

**Example:**

```
         // Simple init
        let mainSB: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let loggedInTabController = mainSB.instantiateViewController(identifier: "loggedInTabController")
        self.window!.rootViewController = loggedInTabController
```