# LogIn Navigation/Segue for iOS 13.2 using Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, ios13

I am trying to implement **SignIn with Google** for my **iOS 13.2** app using **Firebase**. How do I implement a `segue` from the LogIn Page to HomeScreen(a `ViewController`) as soon as the User has signed in.

There is a method attached to `AppDelegate` through `GIDSignInDelegate` which informs us when the user has signed in. I want to `segue` at that point to the home screen. This code is in the `AppDelegate`, and I am not able to use `AppDelegate's` `window` to load from `StoryBoard` because of the new `SceneDelegate` behaviour.

```
func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
        if (error == nil) {
          // Perform any operations on signed in user here.
          // ...
            print("User signed in")

            //place to perform segue
            //write code for segue here

        }
        else {
          print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
        if user != nil
        {
        guard let authentication = user.authentication else { return }
          let credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: authentication.idToken,
                                                            accessToken: authentication.accessToken)
          // ...
        Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (authResult, error) in
          if let error = error {
            // ...
            return
          }
          // User is signed in
          // ...          
        }
        }       
    }
```

Expected result : https://stackoverflow.com/a/27136455/6311566
but this is not working in **iOS 13.2**

Answer (score 0):

**OLD WAY**

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        let rootVC = window?.rootViewController

        return true
    }
```

This is because AppDelegate.swift doesn't have window property anymore. Now you must use SceneDelegate.swift to change root view controller. Like shown in this example:

**WHAT TO DO NOW**

Now, you’ll be moving that code over to your app’s SceneDelegate Swift file:

```
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

     var window: UIWindow?


    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
         // Use this method to optionally configure and attach the UIWindow `window` to the provided UIWindowScene `scene`.
         // If using a storyboard, the `window` property will automatically be initialized and attached to the scene.
         // This delegate does not imply the connecting scene or session are new (see `application:configurationForConnectingSceneSession` instead).
        guard let _ = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }

        // Create the root view controller as needed
        let vc = ViewController()
        let nc = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)

        // Create the window. Be sure to use this initializer and not the frame one.
        let win = UIWindow(windowScene: winScene) 
        win.rootViewController = nc
        win.makeKeyAndVisible()
        window = win
    }

    // ... the rest of SceneDelegate
}
```

Comment: the problem is that my AppDelegate contains the code block that tells me when the user has signed in. I need to segue at that moment, that code isn't available in SceneDelegate.

Comment: Okay i understood but before segue you need to create root using UIWindowScene to segue after user has signed In.

Comment: From the AppDelegate class you can not perform segue. So this line will never work from your AppDelegate class.self.window?.rootViewController?.performSegue

Comment: Here is an example that works in iOS 13 : https://github.com/mattneub/RegistrationExample

Comment: ok, thanks for the response, need to read about SceneDelegate. In the meantime it's possible to access window in AppDelegate using            
`let window = UIApplication.shared.windows.first` 
This works for me as a quick-fix.